# Installing and running browser in colab for selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, firefox, google-colaboratory, python-webbrowser

I know google colab can be used for selenium module, but before using selenium, there should be a browser in colab virtual machine, so I have successfully installed firefox in colab by using the commands

```
!apt-get update
!apt install firefox
```

but when I try to run firefox with the command

```
!firefox
```

it throws an error

> src/tcmalloc.cc:283] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7f4e34915040 
>   Redirecting call to abort() to mozalloc_abort

The same problem occurs with other browsers such as chromium-browser and chrome.
I even tried

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get('firefox').open('https://www.youtube.com')
```

but it throws an error saying

> could not found browser location

So in overall I need the solution for this error which occurs while running a browser

> Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7f4e34915040

Comment: @Jairath: Please don't put program names and package names in code brackets ``. Better improve the spelling and grammar and other aspects of a (soon to be) good question.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot install firefox. But if you can use Chrome. Here's the code.

```py
# install chromium, its driver, and selenium
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install selenium
# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get("https://www.website.com")
print(wd.page_source)  # results
# divs = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('div')
```

Comment: I tried the code, but colab failed with ```WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)```

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to install and run selenium in google colab with firefox driver.

1. Install Firefox driver:

```
!apt-get update  
!apt install firefox
```

2. Install Selenium:

```
!pip install selenium
```

3. Import dependencies:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
```

4. Define a function to build a scraper:

```
def selenium_firefox_agent(driver_path="geckodriver"):
    firefox_driver_path = f'{driver_path}'
    user_agent = 'Mozilla'
    firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
    firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')
    firefox_options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(
        executable_path=firefox_driver_path,
        options=firefox_options
    )
    print('Scraper setup complete!')
    return driver
```

5. Run the scraper:

```
crawler = selenium_firefox_agent()
crawler.get("https://www.google.com/")
source = crawler.page_source
```