# How to install firefox on google colab to use it for selenium testing?

Tags: selenium, firefox, google-colaboratory, geckodriver

I am trying to run a python selenium script on google colab and I need to install Firefox on GC. i don't want to use chrome because it doesn't support emojis like firefox do.

what are the commands that I should run to install Firefox on Google Colab?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to run selenium in google colab with firefox, but to install firefox on colab run this code:

```
!apt-get update
!apt install firefox
```

See also:

- [Installing and running browser in colab for selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042043/installing-and-running-browser-in-colab-for-selenium)